# Get value of integer variable for dynamic loading

Tags: javascript, webview, electron

I'm trying to dynamically create elements and add an Event Listener to them. Here's some code:

```
var marks = {
  list:[{
    selected: "content",
    url: "http://youtube.com/feed/subscriptions",
    trait: "id"
  },{
    selected: "js-streams streams items",
    url: "http://twitch.tv/directory/following",
    trait: "class"
  }]
};

var l = marks.list.length;

var web = "<webview src='https://youtube.com/feed/subscriptions' preload='preload.js' disablewebsecurity></webview>";    

for(var i = 0; i < l; i++){
  var webadd = "<webview id=web" + i + " src=" + marks.list[i].url + " preload='preload.js' disablewebsecurity></webview>";
  $('#canvas1').append(webadd);

  document.getElementById("web" + (i)).addEventListener("dom-ready", function() {
        console.log("nice" + (i)); // <-- This line most likely needs changing
  });
}
```

Right now, I'm able to get my elements and an event listener on each, but when it comes to console log, it prints out `"nice2"` twice. Is there a way to get that line to get `var i`'s value as an integer instead of `i` itself? Ideally, I want it to be printing out `nice0` and `nice1`. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better use a forEach loop. This way you can have a closure and keep you context. also reads better.

```
 mark.list.forEach(function(item, i){
   var webadd = "<webview id=web" + i + " src=" + item.url + " preload='preload.js' disablewebsecurity></webview>";
   $('#canvas1').append(webadd);

  document.getElementById("web" + i).addEventListener("dom-ready", function() {
        console.log("nice" + i); // <-- 
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an extra function that creates your event listener and binds the current `i` to it:

```
document.getElementById("web" + (i)).addEventListener("dom-ready", (function(n) { 
    return function() {
        console.log("nice" + (n));
    }
})(i));
```